# Efficient java data structure to delete and retrieve information?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a situation where I have need a data structure that I can add strings to. This data structure is very large.

The specific qualities I need it have are:

1. get(index)
2. delete a certain number of entries that were added initially when the limit exceeds.(LIFO)

I've tried using an ArrayList but the delete operation is o(n) and for a linkedList the traverse or get() operation will be o(n).

What other options do I have?

Comment: define 'very large'....?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything pre-existing in Java that can do that.  Though I haven't exhaustively searched all of the queue variants.

Comment: LinkedList has a `get(index)` operator, plus enqueuing/dequeuing front and rear.

Comment: Anywhere between 50,000-80,000 strings. It has the potential of increasing too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) - one thats implemented with an array under the hood.

Comment: I am not that familiar with a circular buffer.Will it maintain the  order in which the elements are inserted?

Comment: yes. get(index) is O(1) and so is delete, but, you can only delete the oldest(or newest) entries. you generally specify a maximum size for array backed implementations, and it self deletes the oldest entry when you add a new entry, if the new entry would overflow the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

LinkedHashSet might be of interest. It is effectively a HashSet but it also maintains a LinkedList to allow a predictable iteration order - and therefore can also be used as a FIFO queue, with the nice added benefit that it can't contain duplicate entries.

Because it is a HashSet too, searches (as opposed to scans) can be O(1) if they can match on `equals()`

You can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658364/java-what-is-the-best-way-to-find-elements-in-a-sorted-list) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452891/java-search-collection-of-strings-providing-the-first-few-characters) too.